# Conditionally set Textbox Fill in RDLC

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I am passing a datasource with multiple rows to the rdlc. When I bind it to the grid there are columns called AcknowledgeBy and AcknowledgedOn. If the AcknowledgedOn date is greater than AcknowledgeBy date or if it is empty I want to highlight the cell red. I am adding the following expressions to the "Fill" property of the textbox.

When I use this code it will highlight any dates that are greater than the AcknowledgeBy date correctly

```
=Iif(Fields!AcknowledgedOn.Value > Fields!AcknowledgeBy.Value, "#ff9e9e", "Transparent")
```

But if I add a second Iif to the false statement it will no longer highlight the ones that were greater but it will highlight the empty results.

```
=Iif(Fields!AcknowledgedOn.Value > Fields!AcknowledgeBy.Value, "#ff9e9e", Iif(Fields!AcknowledgedOn.Value = "", "#ff9e9e", "Transparent"))
```

Can someone point out what my issue is?

Comment: try this =IIF(Fields!AcknowledgedOn.Value="" or Fields!AcknowledgedOn.Value> Fields!AcknowledgedBy.Value,"#ff9e9e",Transparent)

Comment: I tried using the or and it is doing the same thing. It is still only highlighting the empty boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure why I could not use the = operator but I was able to get it to work using "Like". The Like operator is used for comparing two strings.

```
=IIf(Fields!AcknowledgedOn.Value > Fields!AcknowledgeBy.Value Or Fields!AcknowledgedOn.Value Like "", "#ff9e9e", "Transparent")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IsNothing`:

```
=IIf(Fields!AcknowledgedOn.Value > Fields!AcknowledgeBy.Value Or IsNothing(Fields!AcknowledgedOn.Value), "#ff9e9e", "Transparent")
```